# Division by zero error while working on getting data to excel using ADOB connection from database

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel, t-sql

I was trying to call sql query from a macro and getting division by zero error.
The same macro works when i run a small query. The query is huge and has multiple select statements. I have included 'Set Arithabort On' and 'Set Arithabort off in my SQL query. The macro is generating headers from the SQL table but not the data when i am using CopyFromRecordset to spreadsheet.
Please let me know if you need more information.

Screenshot:

[image: Screen Shot Attached]

```vb
Sub trial()
    Dim Cnn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim Rst As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim ConnectionString, SqlTextFile, SqlStatement As String

     'Prevent screenupdating when this macro runs
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

     'Clear the destination sheet
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.ClearContents


     'Connection to SQl Server
    ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=.......;Initial Catalog=...........;Trusted_connection=yes;"

    Cnn.Open ConnectionString
    Cnn.CommandTimeout = 900

    SqlTextFile = "C:\Users\Domain Name\Desktop\SQL FILE\SQLQuery2.sql"
    Debug.Print SqlTextFile
    Dim hFile As Long
    hFile = FreeFile
    Open SqlTextFile For Input As #hFile
    SqlStatement = Input$(LOF(hFile), hFile)
    Close #hFile
    Debug.Print SqlStatement


    Rst.Open SqlStatement, Cnn

            For intColIndex = 0 To Rst.Fields.Count - 1
            Selection.Offset(0, intColIndex).Value = Rst.Fields(intColIndex).Name
            Next

        'Copy Data to Excel'
    Sheet1.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset Rst
End Sub
```

```css
 - **MY SQL Query**

SET ARITHABORT OFF  SET ARITHIGNORE OFF  SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF
SELECT DISTINCT A.CONSUMED_TYPE,C.ACCT_IDFR, A.URJA_TYPE_NAME,
C.TRANSACTIONID AS PREV_TRANID, A.ENEINV_IDFR AS PREV_ENEINV_IDFR,SUM(A.TOTAL_CONSUMED) AS PREV_TOTAL_CONSUMED,C.CRAT_USER_ID,
D.TRANSACTIONID AS CURR_TRANID, B.ENEINV_IDFR AS CURR_ENEINV_IDFR, SUM(B.TOTAL_CONSUMED) AS CURR_TOTAL_CONSUMED,D.CRAT_USER_ID,
(SUM(A.TOTAL_CONSUMED)-SUM(B.TOTAL_CONSUMED))AS DIFF, 
(((SUM(A.TOTAL_CONSUMED)-SUM(B.TOTAL_CONSUMED))*100)/SUM(A.TOTAL_CONSUMED))AS VARIATION
FROM UMS_CONSUMPTION_BY_METER A, UMS_CONSUMPTION_BY_METER B, UMS_ENEINV C,UMS_ENEINV D
WHERE A.URJA_TYPE_NAME=B.URJA_TYPE_NAME AND A.ENEINV_IDFR=C.ENEINV_IDFR AND B.ENEINV_IDFR=D.ENEINV_IDFR 
AND C.ACCT_IDFR=D.ACCT_IDFR AND A.CONSUMED_TYPE=B.CONSUMED_TYPE AND A.CONSUMED_TYPE='Consumption'
AND YEAR(A.MAXENDDATE)=YEAR(B.MAXENDDATE)-1 AND MONTH(A.MAXENDDATE)=MONTH(B.MAXENDDATE) 
AND D.CRAT_USER_ID<>'SYSTEM' ---AND D.LU_DATE>='03/01/2014'
AND CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR,D.LU_DATE,101)AS DATETIME)=CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),101)AS DATETIME)
GROUP BY A.CONSUMED_TYPE,C.ACCT_IDFR, A.URJA_TYPE_NAME,C.TRANSACTIONID, A.ENEINV_IDFR, C.CRAT_USER_ID,
D.TRANSACTIONID, B.ENEINV_IDFR, D.CRAT_USER_ID HAVING SUM(A.TOTAL_CONSUMED)>SUM(B.TOTAL_CONSUMED) AND
(((SUM(A.TOTAL_CONSUMED)-SUM(B.TOTAL_CONSUMED))*100)/SUM(A.TOTAL_CONSUMED))>'50' 
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT A.CONSUMED_TYPE,C.ACCT_IDFR, A.URJA_TYPE_NAME,
C.TRANSACTIONID AS PREV_TRANID, A.ENEINV_IDFR AS PREV_ENEINV_IDFR,SUM(A.TOTAL_CONSUMED) AS PREV_CONSUMED,C.CRAT_USER_ID,
D.TRANSACTIONID AS CURR_TRANID, B.ENEINV_IDFR AS CURR_ENEINV_IDFR, SUM(B.TOTAL_CONSUMED) AS CURR_CONSUMED,D.CRAT_USER_ID,
(SUM(A.TOTAL_CONSUMED)-SUM(B.TOTAL_CONSUMED))AS DIFF, 
(((SUM(B.TOTAL_CONSUMED)-SUM(A.TOTAL_CONSUMED))*100)/SUM(A.TOTAL_CONSUMED))AS VARIATION
FROM UMS_CONSUMPTION_BY_METER A, UMS_CONSUMPTION_BY_METER B, UMS_ENEINV C,UMS_ENEINV D
WHERE A.URJA_TYPE_NAME=B.URJA_TYPE_NAME AND A.ENEINV_IDFR=C.ENEINV_IDFR AND B.ENEINV_IDFR=D.ENEINV_IDFR 
AND C.ACCT_IDFR=D.ACCT_IDFR AND A.CONSUMED_TYPE=B.CONSUMED_TYPE AND A.CONSUMED_TYPE='Consumption'
AND YEAR(A.MAXENDDATE)=YEAR(B.MAXENDDATE)-1 AND MONTH(A.MAXENDDATE)=MONTH(B.MAXENDDATE) 
AND D.CRAT_USER_ID<>'SYSTEM' ---AND D.LU_DATE>='03/01/2014'
AND CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR,D.LU_DATE,101)AS DATETIME)=CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),101)AS DATETIME)
GROUP BY A.CONSUMED_TYPE,C.ACCT_IDFR, A.URJA_TYPE_NAME,C.TRANSACTIONID, A.ENEINV_IDFR, C.CRAT_USER_ID,
D.TRANSACTIONID, B.ENEINV_IDFR, D.CRAT_USER_ID HAVING SUM(B.TOTAL_CONSUMED)>SUM(A.TOTAL_CONSUMED) 
AND (((SUM(B.TOTAL_CONSUMED)-SUM(A.TOTAL_CONSUMED))*100)/SUM(A.TOTAL_CONSUMED))>'50' 
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT A.CONSUMED_TYPE,C.ACCT_IDFR, A.URJA_TYPE_NAME,
C.TRANSACTIONID AS PREV_TRANID, A.ENEINV_IDFR AS PREV_ENEINV_IDFR,SUM(A.TOTAL_CONSUMED) AS PREV_TOTAL_CONSUMED,C.CRAT_USER_ID,
D.TRANSACTIONID AS CURR_TRANID, B.ENEINV_IDFR AS CURR_ENEINV_IDFR, SUM(B.TOTAL_CONSUMED) AS CURR_TOTAL_CONSUMED,D.CRAT_USER_ID,
(SUM(A.TOTAL_CONSUMED)-SUM(B.TOTAL_CONSUMED))AS DIFF, 
(((SUM(A.TOTAL_CONSUMED)-SUM(B.TOTAL_CONSUMED))*100)/SUM(A.TOTAL_CONSUMED))AS VARIATION
FROM UMS_CONSUMPTION_BY_METER A, UMS_CONSUMPTION_BY_METER B, UMS_ENEINV C,UMS_ENEINV D
WHERE A.URJA_TYPE_NAME=B.URJA_TYPE_NAME AND A.ENEINV_IDFR=C.ENEINV_IDFR AND B.ENEINV_IDFR=D.ENEINV_IDFR 
AND C.ACCT_IDFR=D.ACCT_IDFR AND A.CONSUMED_TYPE=B.CONSUMED_TYPE AND A.CONSUMED_TYPE='Demand'
AND YEAR(A.MAXENDDATE)=YEAR(B.MAXENDDATE)-1 AND MONTH(A.MAXENDDATE)=MONTH(B.MAXENDDATE) 
AND D.CRAT_USER_ID<>'SYSTEM' ---AND D.LU_DATE>='03/01/2014'
AND CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR,D.LU_DATE,101)AS DATETIME)=CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),101)AS DATETIME)
GROUP BY A.CONSUMED_TYPE,C.ACCT_IDFR, A.URJA_TYPE_NAME,C.TRANSACTIONID, A.ENEINV_IDFR, C.CRAT_USER_ID,
D.TRANSACTIONID, B.ENEINV_IDFR, D.CRAT_USER_ID HAVING SUM(A.TOTAL_CONSUMED)>SUM(B.TOTAL_CONSUMED) AND
(((SUM(A.TOTAL_CONSUMED)-SUM(B.TOTAL_CONSUMED))*100)/SUM(A.TOTAL_CONSUMED))>'50' 
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT A.CONSUMED_TYPE,C.ACCT_IDFR, A.URJA_TYPE_NAME,
C.TRANSACTIONID AS PREV_TRANID, A.ENEINV_IDFR AS PREV_ENEINV_IDFR,SUM(A.TOTAL_CONSUMED) AS PREV_CONSUMED,C.CRAT_USER_ID,
D.TRANSACTIONID AS CURR_TRANID, B.ENEINV_IDFR AS CURR_ENEINV_IDFR, SUM(B.TOTAL_CONSUMED) AS CURR_CONSUMED,D.CRAT_USER_ID,
(SUM(A.TOTAL_CONSUMED)-SUM(B.TOTAL_CONSUMED))AS DIFF, 
(((SUM(B.TOTAL_CONSUMED)-SUM(A.TOTAL_CONSUMED))*100)/SUM(A.TOTAL_CONSUMED))AS VARIATION
FROM UMS_CONSUMPTION_BY_METER A, UMS_CONSUMPTION_BY_METER B, UMS_ENEINV C,UMS_ENEINV D
WHERE A.URJA_TYPE_NAME=B.URJA_TYPE_NAME AND A.ENEINV_IDFR=C.ENEINV_IDFR AND B.ENEINV_IDFR=D.ENEINV_IDFR 
AND C.ACCT_IDFR=D.ACCT_IDFR AND A.CONSUMED_TYPE=B.CONSUMED_TYPE AND A.CONSUMED_TYPE='Demand'
AND YEAR(A.MAXENDDATE)=YEAR(B.MAXENDDATE)-1 AND MONTH(A.MAXENDDATE)=MONTH(B.MAXENDDATE) 
AND D.CRAT_USER_ID<>'SYSTEM' ---AND D.LU_DATE>='03/01/2014'
AND CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR,D.LU_DATE,101)AS DATETIME)=CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),101)AS DATETIME)
GROUP BY A.CONSUMED_TYPE,C.ACCT_IDFR, A.URJA_TYPE_NAME,C.TRANSACTIONID, A.ENEINV_IDFR, C.CRAT_USER_ID,
D.TRANSACTIONID, B.ENEINV_IDFR, D.CRAT_USER_ID HAVING SUM(B.TOTAL_CONSUMED)>SUM(A.TOTAL_CONSUMED) 
AND (((SUM(B.TOTAL_CONSUMED)-SUM(A.TOTAL_CONSUMED))*100)/SUM(A.TOTAL_CONSUMED))>'50'
SET ARITHABORT ON  SET ARITHIGNORE ON  SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
```

Comment: If the SQL query is causing that error we need to see the SQL query.

Comment: Alex...I have shared the SQL query now. This query runs fine on SQL Management Studio. The records and data are perfect. Just wanted to create this as an automated task.

Answer (score 3):

Take a peek at the denominators in your **SQL query**, and consider replacing them with:

```
NullIf(...some expression... ,0)
```

So, if the denominator equals ZERO, then the expression would essentially be n/null which will return NULL and not throw an error

Comment: I might need a help from you. i have added sql query as well.

Comment: @johnk Goodness!  My advice is start smaller and incrementally build